# Android Image loader library with support for ETags, If-Modified-Since

Tags: java, android, caching, if-modified-since, etag

I've been using for some time [**Android Http Image Manager**](http://code.google.com/p/android-http-image-manager/), and recently I switched over to [**Android Universal Image Loader**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

I'm afraid neither of them have support for verifying if local cache is up-to-date.

What I'm currently looking for is an Image Loader library with community support and support for checking remote changes via [**ETag**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) and/or [**If-Modified-Since**](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1945/58.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is answered from Github AUIL issue tracker. Thank you [NOSTRA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913762/nostra)

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/75

```
public class URLConnectionImageDownloader extends ImageDownloader {
    @Override
    public InputStream getStreamFromNetwork(URI imageUri) throws IOException {
        URLConnection conn = imageUri.toURL().openConnection();
        // check etag/last-modification-date/... params
        // if image was changed then we should delete cached image from memory cache and disc cache

        // Delete image from caches
        String uri = imageUri.toString();
        File imageFile = ImageLoader.getDiscCache().get(uri)
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            imageFile.delete();
        }
        MemoryCacheAware<String, Bitmap memoryCache = ImageLoader.getMemoryCache();
        for (String cacheKey : memoryCache.keys()) {
            if (cacheKey.contains(uri) {
                memoryCache.remove(cacheKey);
            }
        }


        return new FlushedInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention as what to return in this `getStreamFromNetwork()` method in case when etag was NOT changed?

Comment: What I'm thinking is of maintaining a local disk based hashmap of imageUris and their etags. And deciding upon that whether to delete the existing image and fetch the new one or not. Is this implementation fine or is there any better way to achieve this?